# How can I run multiple SQL Server containers in Azure and make sure data is replicated across them?

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-sql-database

title describes pretty much what we are trying to accomplish in our organization.

We have a very database intensive application, and our single SQL Server machine is struggling.

We are reading articles about Azure, Docker and Kubernetes but we are afraid of trying these technologies.

Our problem is data replication.

How can we have scalability here? If we have three different SQL Server instances in three different containers, How does data get replicated across them? (meaning, user inserts a new product into a shared library, other user accessing a different node/container should be able to see that product).

Maybe we don't need containers at all and Azure provides another way to scale databases?

We really appreciate any help from you guys.

Regards, Cris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise against trying to run your databases on K8s. Kubernetes Containers should generally be stateless application, and were not designed for persistent data storage. Azure provides a Database as a Service, which will be able to scale appropriately with your needs([Azure Pricing for Cloud SQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/managed/)

We once experimented with running our Postgres DB inside of a Kubernetes pod, but I was terrified to change anything. Not worth it, and not what the system was designed for.

If you are really really committed to this path, you can check out MySQL NDB Cluster[MySQL for distributed environments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster.html). It should be adaptable to the Kubernetes paradigm.

Comment: Hey Teddy, thanks for your reply. What you are saying makes total sense, and you can find a similar opinion in the following article: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/kubernetes-state-of-stateful-apps. However, they also mention about two integrated solutions K8s provide: StatefulSets & DaemonSets. Any thoughts about them?

Comment: They do a great job of going over the pros and cons. Both these options are now out of beta and available as GA on k8s 1.9, so I guess that is an endorsement. I'm sure you've been hearing a ton about Docker and Kubernetes. They are really great tools for developer operations, and have simplified our infrastructure greatly. But, if you are looking to use kubernetes solely for a replicated database, there are much simpler solutions that are tried and true. Azure's hosted MySQL would be more than sufficient without all the hassle of managing a k8s cluster.